# Need Application to show in Applications

Tags: release-loki

I can only run an app from the terminal

Is there a simple way to get my app to show in my applications?

Answer (score 1):

In app menu? Sure there is.
[App Editor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/)

Install it, configure icon, app name and shortcut, and your set.